# Remove special characters from NSString

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring

I am doing JSON parsing. There are many different substrings in response which I want to remove, because HTML or ASCII values comes in my response. Like `&#39;` or `$quot;` or `&` etc.

I am using following method for remove substring, but how I can remove all ASCII or HTML substrings ?

```
NSString *strTe=[strippedString
         stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#39 ;" withString:@""];
```

**Edit:**
Look this [page](http://www.asciitable.com/) under the HTML Table Heading, I got these symbols in my response.

Comment: if your are getting data in array then once try like this NSString *bullet = [[descriptionArray objectAtIndex:k] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#39;" withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]];

Comment: Have a look at this. `NSString *strTe = [strippedString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Answer (score 1):

This code may help your query :

```
- (NSString *)flattenHTML:(NSString *)html 
{    
    NSScanner *theScanner;
    NSString *text = nil;
    theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:html];

    while ([theScanner isAtEnd] == NO) 
   {    
        [theScanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:NULL] ; 
        [theScanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:&text] ;
        html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@>", text] withString:@""];
   }

   html = [html stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

   return html;
}
```

Comment: you can modify the above functionality ..
 html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&#39", text] withString:@""];

and more ..